# Defining national borders in TIF file and cutting away excess map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, mapping, denmark

In QGIS I am trying to create a shaded relief map of Denmark.

I have managed to fetch the data from https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/elevation/copernicus-dem/elevation, but I am clueless as to what to do now to cut away excess layer to create a file I can process further in Blender?

[image]

Comment: http://geosupportsystem.se/2021/10/20/qgis-och-blender/

Comment: Translated to english: https://geosupportsystem-se.translate.goog/2021/10/20/qgis-och-blender/?_x_tr_sl=sv&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_sch=http

Comment: @BERA Just what I was looking for - thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: https://geosupportsystem-se.translate.goog/2021/10/20/qgis-och-blender/?_x_tr_sl=sv&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_sch=http

A nice example of how to combine QGIS and Blender to create a map with a 3D effect